# Issue properly using type from a react HOC

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am having some issues getting my types correct when using an HOC. I have this HOC

```js
export interface IWithLangProps {
    lang: ILang;
}

const withLang = <T extends object>(Comp: React.ComponentType<T>):
    React.ComponentClass<T & IWithLangProps, any> | React.FunctionComponent<T & IWithLangProps> =>
     class WrapperComponent extends Component<T & IWithLangProps> {
        render(): JSX.Element {
            return (
                <LangConsumer>
                    {(value: IWithLangProps): JSX.Element =>
                        <Comp {...this.props as T} lang={value.lang} />
                    }
                </LangConsumer>
            );

    }
};
```

Now I have a component which uses the HOC.

```js
export interface IGridSearchProps {
    searchDelay?: number;
    onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

/**
 * GridSearch for displaying search field on data grids
 */
const GridSearch = (props: IGridSearchProps): JSX.Element => {
    const {
        onChange,
        searchDelay = 300,
        lang, // Typescript errors here since it cant find lang provided by the HOC
    } = props;

    return (
        <Search
            placeholder={lang.trans('s.search_the_table')}
            onChange={onChange}
            searchDelay={searchDelay}
        />
    );
};

GridSearch.displayName = 'GridSearch';

export default withLang<IGridSearchProps>(GridSearch);
```

Here is my problem. How do I get `GridSearch` to properly know about lang? I tried extending `IGridSearchProps` with `IWithLangProps` but any component using `GridSearch` expects `lang` to be in the props if I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `GridSearch` needs `lang` it should be in the props of `GridSearch`. `withLang` can then remove `lang` from the props of the resulting component using `Omit`:

```
export interface IWithLangProps {
  lang: ILang;
}
type Omit<T, K extends PropertyKey> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>> // Included in 3.5 
const withLang = <T extends object>(Comp: React.ComponentType<T>): React.ComponentType<Omit<T, keyof IWithLangProps>> =>
  class WrapperComponent extends Component<Omit<T, keyof IWithLangProps>> {
      render(): JSX.Element {
          return (
              <LangConsumer>
                  {(value: IWithLangProps): JSX.Element =>
                      <Comp {...this.props as T} lang={value.lang} />
                  }
              </LangConsumer>
          );

  }
};
export interface IGridSearchProps extends IWithLangProps{
  searchDelay?: number;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

/**
* GridSearch for displaying search field on data grids
*/
const GridSearch = (props: IGridSearchProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {
      onChange,
      searchDelay = 300,
      lang, // Typescript errors here since it cant find lang provided by the HOC
  } = props;

  return (
      <Search
          placeholder={lang.trans('s.search_the_table')}
          onChange={onChange}
          searchDelay={searchDelay}
      />
  );
};

GridSearch.displayName = 'GridSearch';

export default withLang(GridSearch);
```

Comment: I have a question. Is it possible for `IGridSearchProps` or `GridSearch` to know about `lang` w/o extending it in the interface definition? Since this HOC is used in a lot of places it would be nice if that part could be automated.

Comment: @topched you need to add it to each component somehow, another way is to use an intersection `(props: IGridSearchProps & IWithLangProps) .....`

Comment: Yeah I kind of figured. Was hoping there was some magic where I didn't need to grab the interface everywhere that used withLang. Thanks anyways it does the trick.